# How to Populate Label with String Array on ComboBox Item Selection in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox, label

I have an application in VB.Net where I'm trying to fill a label with some string data that I have in an array. I have a `ComboBox` which holds some states as the index collection/values. When I select a particular value in the combobox, I want to pull string data from the assigned array, and populate the label with it as a "clickable link a browser window. I'm lost on this, yet here is what I have in my code stub:

```
Private Sub cboSelectState_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   cboSelectState.SelectedIndexChanged

    'Create a string array
    Dim AlabamaCities() As String = {"http://www.rolltide.com/", "http://www.crimsontidehoops.com/", "http://centralalabamapride.org/"}
    Dim strAlabama As String

    'Populate label with the array data, on a particular value selection in combo box.
    If cboSelectState.SelectedValue("Georgia") Then
        strAlabama = CStr(AlabamaCities(3))
        lblLinkOutput.Text = strAlabama
    End If

End Sub
```

So when I pick Alabama in my combo box, I want the label to show:

**http://www.rolltide.com

http://www.crimsontidehoops.com

http://centralalabamapride.org**

The links will be clickable from the label and populate in the same tab whenever clicked. I haven't tried the clickable link part yet, and I will try once I get this down.

I know it's probably bad starting form out the gate.  But I'm trying to get the form down to gain the knowledge and plan out a bigger project, and accomplish something better when I think of it. I appreciate your knowledge and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would make sense to use a `Dictionary` to store the data.  The state names will be the keys and the values would be the arrays of URLs.  You would then display the keys in the `ComboBox` and, when a selection is made, use the selected key to get the corresponding value from the `Dictionary`.

At that point, you won't be using a `Label` if you want clickable links.  You should use a `TableLayoutPanel` as a container and then add one `LinkLabel` to the table for each URL in the array.  You can then use a single handler for all the `LinkClicked` events.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, but I'm new to using `Dictionary` data type, and found the syntax to be quite confusing. I managed to accomplish my goal using an array. However, once the links appear in my `LinkLabel`, they appear as a whole string. I don't want that. Any way you can give me a slight visual of you what you're trying to convey?